# Producing a heatmap from a pandas dataframe with rows of the form (x,y,z), where z is intended to be the heat value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

Let's say I have a dataframe with this structure

[image: Example dataframe content]

and I intend to transform it into something like this (done laboriously and quite manually):

[image: Example of heatmap]

Is there a simple call to (say) a seaborn or plotly function that would do this? Something like

```
heatmap(df, x='Dose', y='Distance', z='Passrate')
```

or perhaps a simple way of restructuring the dataframe to facilitate using sns.heatmap or plotly's imshow, or similar? It seems strange to me that I cannot find a straightforward way of putting data formatted in this way into a high-level plotting function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to get your data in the correct shape first.

**Setup:** create some random data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

p_rate = np.arange(0,100)/np.arange(0,100).sum()

data = {'Dose': np.repeat(np.arange(0,3.5,0.5), 10),
        'Distance': np.tile(np.arange(0,3.5,0.5), 10),
        'Passrate': np.random.choice(np.arange(0,100), size=70,
                                     p=p_rate)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code:** pivot and apply [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='Distance', 
                          columns='Dose', 
                          values='Passrate', 
                          aggfunc='mean').sort_index(ascending=False)

sns.heatmap(df_pivot, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm')
```

**Result:**

[image: example heatmap]